# How to get PublicKey from AsymmetricCipherKeyPair, not publickeycipher parameters?

Tags: java, java-me, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I am generating a key pair on the platform using the [Bouncy Castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouncy_Castle_%28cryptography%29) package.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

ECKeyPairGenerator pGen = new ECKeyPairGenerator();

ECKeyGenerationParameters genParam = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(params,random);

pGen.init(genParam);

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair pair = pGen.generateKeyPair();
```

Here, `pair` is of type `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`. And, i need to generate a X509V1Certificate at the server using this pair. But, X509Certificate's `setPublicKey(PublicKey pubkey)` accepts only objects of type `PublicKey`. So I need to retrieve a `PublicKey` from an `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` at server. But, I am getting `ECPublicKeyParameters`, which is not accepted in the `setPublicKey` method.

So, my requirement here is to get a `PublicKey` from an `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`.

Comment: If you are in the Java ME environment then you don't have java.security.PublicKey or java.security.cert.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I am sending public key of j2me client application to server to get client certificate. Server receives public key, but while generating X509Certificate, it is unable to setPublicKey() using received public key. Since received public key of type ECPublicKeyparameters. So I want to change the type of this public key to PublicKey at server. Please mention suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So how are you sending the key from the j2me client to the server? Did you serialize it or encode it in some way?

Comment: i am sending Public key in the form of bytes to server. I opened connection with server and i used the methods write(byte[] ) to send data in bytes...

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way is to use BouncyCastle as JavaCryptoProvider :

1. Generate KeyPair

   ```
   KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC");
   ECGenParameterSpec ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec(keyAlg);
   kpg.initialize(ecsp);
   KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
   ```
2. Make X509v1 Cert

   ```
   X509V1CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();
   X500Principal dnName = new X500Principal("CN=C3");
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
   certGen.setSerialNumber(keyId);
   certGen.setIssuerDN(dnName);
   certGen.setNotBefore(new Date());
   certGen.setNotAfter(c.getTime());
   certGen.setSubjectDN(dnName);                      
   certGen.setPublicKey(keyPair.getPublic());
   certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256withECDSA");
   certGen.generate(keyPair.getPrivate(), "BC");
   ```

Comment: The lightweight bouncy castle library (used in J2ME platform) does not contain the KeyPairGenerator class.
SO, I have used ECKeyPairGenerator in place of KeyPairGenerator class. And the pair that we have obtained from this,in the form of AsymmetricCipherKeyPair. But X.509V1CertificateGenerator does not allow a keypair of this type. So, I need to convert this form to KeyPair form. Thank you.